# Linux restart process after it dies

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I have a PHP script running in CentOs which is a server for creating new accounts for an online game, the script is linked with invision power board so sometimes when IPB encounters an error it kills off the PHP script which included it (the server)

I need the script to run all the time even if it gets killed off, so technically auto restarting it self, I tried this solution:

**sh script:**

```
while true; do
php -f AccountServer.php
done
```

But for some strange reason it still finds a way to stop working after a period of time even when this script is running through screen..

Is there any other techniques I could use to ensure the process will never die?

Comment: It's better to use Monit (http://mmonit.com/monit/) for such tasks.

Comment: Have you considered [Upstart](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/281586/How-to-write-CentOS-initialization-scripts-with-Upstart) with `respawn`? Also, if you're running your script in a shell, you can either start it with `nohup` or make sure you `disown` it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a cron job to run every X amount of time to make sure its still running and if not start it again.